# Appending element without duplication

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to append an element to the end of a span on a webpage but the problem is that because there are more than one spans, the element duplicates itself to be appended to each span instead of just going at the very end of the last span. Any solutions/suggestions?

*Note: I MUST keep the span*

**JS**

```
$('#face').css({"float":"right"}).appendTo('span');
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="face" style="background-color: #000000; width: 30px; height: 20px;"></div>
<br/><br/>
<span>He fell off his horse</span>
<span>and broke his ankle</span>
```

Comment: *"I want to append an element "* - which element? *"the element duplicates itself to be appended to each span instead of just going at the very end of the last span"* - where is the code that does this?

Comment: It's alright TJ. There are answers below. Thanks.

Comment: Well, there'll be answers. but this isn't the right way to ask a good question. If getting your job done is your only intention in being part of SO, then carry on.

Comment: One does not simply ask a question without accepting an answer.

Comment: Thanks TJ, I've been carrying on for a bit now, plus I don't consider what I do a job since it's just a hobby :DD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:last` selector

```
$('#face').css({"float":"right"}).appendTo('span:last');
```

Answer (score 0):

Give each span an id 
e.g `<span id="span1"></span>`

then in Jquery append that particular id referring to it in this way
 `$('#span1').append("YOUR CONTENT")`

You can also use `appendTo()` in the same way

Answer (score 0):

There's a handy jQuery function for just this situation. The "last" function.

```
$('#face').css({"float":"right"}).appendTo($('span').last());
```

See it in action on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0m8wfmav/).